# c# - wpf sqlite crash after publish

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm working on a WPF project that I only need to read from an SQLite db. the application works just fine in debugging and release but after publish it's crash every time it needs to use the SQLite. I do everything that I'm supposed to be done but it is not working. I installed SQLite from nuget. I will include necessary data :

## update :

fixed

## class

```
class Databasehandle
{
    public DataTable SelectQuery(string query)
    {
        SQLiteDataAdapter ad;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SQLiteConnection sqlite = new SQLiteConnection(Loadconnectionstring()))
        {
            try
            {
                SQLiteCommand cmd;
                sqlite.Open();
                cmd = sqlite.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                ad = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                ad.Fill(dt);
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            sqlite.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
    private static string Loadconnectionstring(string id = "default")
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[id].ConnectionString; 
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

## errors

```
Application: rokhanui.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.DllNotFoundException
   at System.Data.SQLite.UnsafeNativeMethods.sqlite3_config_none(System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConfigOpsEnum)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.StaticIsInitialized()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteLog.Initialize(System.String)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(System.String, Boolean)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(System.String)
   at rokhanui.inc.Databasehandle.SelectQuery(System.String)
   at rokhanui.MainWindow.getsorah(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, System.Windows.RoutedEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(System.Object, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(System.Object, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr, System.Windows.Input.InputMode, Int32, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions, Int32, Int32, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(System.Windows.Interop.MSG ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window)
   at rokhanui.App.Main()
```

Comment: Please describe the "crash" including exception/event log details.

Comment: @AlexK. app just closes without any message. is there a way that I can get exception/event log after publish?

Comment: Look in the Windows Event Viewer

Comment: @AlexK. i added the event log

Comment: "I end up adding SQLite.Interop.dll manually to the project. it is not crashing now but db is not working ( showing data )" So this issue is fixed and you now have a totally different issue. Please ask a new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up adding SQLite.Interop.dll manually to the project. it is not crashing now

[image]